How to evaluate $\int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-\frac{B}{2}(x+\frac{1}{B})^2}}{(x-\zeta)^2}dx$
I tried to evaluate the improper integral
$$\int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{-\frac{B}{2}(x+\frac{1}{B})^2}}{(x-\zeta)^2}dx$$
where $B>0$ is real and $\zeta=s+i\epsilon$ with $s \in \mathbb{R}$ ($\epsilon$ has no specific sign) so that there is no pole on the real axis.
I consulted Gradshteyn & Ryzhik, but I could only find special cases of the given integral.
Mathematica does not provide any result neither.
Is there an analytical expression which corresponds to this integral? Thank you any help.
